# Is BPF_LOOP for Linkedlist iteration, viable?, if not what other way I can do it

Tags: ebpf, bpf

I am trying to iterate a linked list in BPF, can I use bpf_loop for this?, if so how?

Tried using bpf_loops, but it required a fixed number to bound the loops, what way I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

These are the comments for `bpf_loop`.

> bpf_loop
>
> For **nr_loops**, call **callback_fn** function
> with **callback_ctx** as the context parameter.
> The **callback_fn** should be a static function and
> the **callback_ctx** should be a pointer to the stack.
> The **flags** is used to control certain aspects of the helper.
> Currently, the **flags** must be 0. Currently, nr_loops is
> limited to 1 << 23 (~8 million) loops.
>
> long (*callback_fn)(u32 index, void *ctx);
>
> where **index** is the current index in the loop. The index
> is zero-indexed.
>
> If **callback_fn** returns 0, the helper will continue to the next
> loop. If return value is 1, the helper will skip the rest of
> the loops and return. Other return values are not used now,
> and will be rejected by the verifier.
>
> Returns
> The number of loops performed, **-EINVAL** for invalid **flags**,
> **-E2BIG** if **nr_loops** exceeds the maximum number of loops.

- You can pass the linked list via the `callback_ctx` which is shared between iterations.
- You can hardcode the number of loops to the max of 1 << 23 (~8 million) (perhaps less, it depends on how the verifier imposes penalties).
- If you can advance the linked list you do so and perform whatever logic you want.
- If you are done or at the end of the linked list you return `1` to
  break out of the loop.
- If you expect to need more than 8M iterations, you can at least detect when you are not done by looking at the return value (perhaps running a second loop, I don't know if that is allowed or not)